# How replace unicode character %F5 in htaccess to make 301 redirect?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, unicode

I have an image with src
`image/cache/data/skus/cake-171%F5123mm-300x300.jpg`

I want to make 301 redirect in htaccess.
According to unicode table `%F5` is `õ`.
But the string

```
RewriteRule ^image/cache/data/skus/cake-171õ123mm-300x300.jpg image/cache/data/skus/cake-171x123mm-300x300.jpg [L,R=301]
```

does not work!

What I do wrong?
In other cases this string works perfectly, but %F5 is real problem...

Comment: Just use the `B` flag in your rewrite rule. Check the docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b

Comment: @icecub
You mean [L,R=301,B] ?
It does not help ((

Comment: If you don't want it to escape it try using `NE` flag.

Comment: The `B` flag escapes non-alphanumeric characters allowing you to use `%` for unicode characters :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use hexcode `\xF5` in your `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^image/cache/data/skus/cake-171\xF5123mm-300x300.jpg /image/cache/data/skus/cake-171x123mm-300x300.jpg [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your `.htaccess` file's encoding is `utf-8` (and **not** ANSI).
2. When you do a redirect you usually want to set the full domain (and not just path).
3. If what you want is only to output the correct file from the correct path you don't really have to use `R=301`, you can use only `[L]`

Comment: 1. UTF-8
2,3. I'm sorry, but does it matter?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you ask... what "does it matter"? the encoding of the `.htaccess` file? yes, it must be UTF-8.